# xs:integer validation issue with pattern restriction and canonical representation

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem where I receive a third party XML document according to a third party XML schema. The schema uses a pattern restriction on an xs:integer element:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="NumericInteger_Length8To8">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Format limitations: n8</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="-?[0-9]{8,8}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

The XML received shows integers of 8 digits where 1 or more leading digits are zeros:

```
<exampleCode>01234567</exampleCode>
```

When I parse this XML it is valid as it matches the pattern. Next, I have to send out the same XML as a text message again. My XML renderer sends out a canonical representation of the integer, so without the leading zero:

```
<exampleCode>1234567</exampleCode>
```

The receiving system tries to validate the message I sent and throws an error as the value 1234567 no longer matches the pattern restriction.

Since the received XML is stored internally as an XML document in my system, it is transformed into a real integer, the lexical representation is lost. Next, when I render the XML document, the initial lexical representation is obviously gone, hence no leading zero. I don't see a nice way around this problem. The only possibility would be for me to alter the XML schema internally, e.g. make the type definition an xs:string so that it is passed without any change, but I would prefer to not touch the (third party) schema.

*My question is whether this is a valid use of the pattern facet for an xs:integer, so is the third party XML schema a valid schema? Does W3 impose restrictions or guidelines on the use of patterns?*

I could only find a few similar issues, e.g.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (Canonical Forms ... section)
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xerces-j-users/200409.mbox/%3C20040909151622.GA9712@hamachi.dyndns.org%3E

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal, but in my view, very bad practice.

W3C isn't in the business of producing guidelines or usage advice, it generally leaves that to others.